# Создание ивента в календаре

Tags: android, google-calendar

Здравствуйте. Создаю ивент в календаре. Но через минуту или меньше он удаляется.

```
values = new ContentValues();

values.put(Events.DTSTART, from.getTime());
values.put(Events.DTEND, to.getTime());

values.put(Events.TITLE, titleSpot.getEditableText().toString());
values.put(Events.ALL_DAY,1);
values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION,  location .getEditableText().toString());
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,
    timeZone.getID());

values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, dis.getEditableText().toString());
values.put(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
values.put(Events.SELF_ATTENDEE_STATUS,
Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);
values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 1);
values.put(Events.GUESTS_CAN_INVITE_OTHERS, 1);
values.put(Events.GUESTS_CAN_MODIFY, 1);
values.put(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
Поменял с 3 на 1.Больше не удаляется.Объясните пожалуйста разницу?
Ещё поменялся из-за этого цвет ивента с коричневого на синий,что лучше

Comment: судя по всему  - это id календаря, в который нужно добавить событие. Цвет приписывается к календарю (поэтому и поменялся цвет). Календаря с id=3 у Вас похоже не было, поэтому и подчищало его.

Comment: Блин, он тоже в итоге удалился. Так мне нужно добавить в стандартный календарь

Answer (score 1):

```
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 0);
```

Так как - то!

Comment: вроде работает.Теперь возникла проблема с апдейтом ивентов.Они удаляются после апдейта=\\

Comment: Не понял. Вы же хотели добывить в стандартный календарь? Он идет по
  values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 0);. Удаляться не должен. Что не обновляется?

Comment: Я пытаюсь его обновить:
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI,eventId);    
cr.update(uri,updateValues(from, to), null, null);
Операция проходит без ошибок , но ивент исчезает из календаря.

Comment: А Вы в манифест добавили:
android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
Если да то надо подумать! Если нет думаю в этом причина.

Comment: Конечно добавил!)
Код кстати для апдейта(заполнение contentvalues)точно такой же как при создании(ну только календарь айди 0 и убрана одна строчка из-за которой ошибка вылетала при апдейте)

Comment: ап ап ап ап